# logstash opensearch ECS disabled Failed to load default template for OpenSearch v2 with ECS disabled

Tags: logstash, opensearch

anyone running latest opensearch with logstash
if you getting below errors

logstash  | [2022-07-16T00:30:42,097][ERROR][logstash.outputs.opensearch][task1] Failed to install template {:message=>"Failed to load default template for OpenSearch v2 with ECS disabled; caused by: #<ArgumentError: Template file '/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch/templates/ecs-disabled/2x.json' could not be found>", :exception=>RuntimeError, :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch/template_manager.rb:33:in `load_default_template'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch/template_manager.rb:21:in` install_template'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch.rb:412:in `install_template'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch.rb:247:in` finish_register'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch.rb:224:in `block in register'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/opensearch/common.rb:83:in` block in after_successful_connection'"]}
logstash  | [2022-07-16T00:30:42,106][ERROR][logstash.outputs.opensearch][task2] Failed to install template {:message=>"Failed to load default template for OpenSearch v2 with ECS disabled; caused by: #<ArgumentError: Template file '/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch/templates/ecs-disabled/2x.json' could not be found>", :exception=>RuntimeError, :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch/template_manager.rb:33:in `load_default_template'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch/template_manager.rb:21:in` install_template'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch.rb:412:in `install_template'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch.rb:247:in` finish_register'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch.rb:224:in `block in register'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/opensearch/common.rb:83:in` block in after_successful_connection'"]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by copying 1x.json to 2x.json.

In this case:

```
cp /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch/templates/ecs-disabled/1x.json /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-opensearch-1.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch/templates/ecs-disabled/2x.json
```